# Place the Sprite image right side of the anchor tag?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I am having the css sprite image.And it works fine but the issue is I want the image right side of the anchor tag's text.But it displays in the left side.The sprite image is here.

http://jstiles.com/temp/1360875952/ctrls/css-sprite.png

Expected result:

```
[Mylinktext]<MyImagehere>
```

Actual result what I am getting is

```
<MyImagehere>[Mylinktext]
```

I don't want to use after pseudo class.Becuase it wont work out in the IE7 browser too.My code is below.

```
.ctrls
    {
        font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:16px;
        color:black;
        background-image: url(images/ctrlsprite.png);
        //background-image: url(images/css-sprite.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        text-decoration:none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left:30px;  
    }
    .ctrls:hover
    {
        background-position: 0px -252px;
        text-decoration:underline;      
    }
    a.magenta
    {
        background-position:0px -144px;
    }
```

And HTML

```
<div>
    <p>Magenta</p>
    <a href="#" class="ctrls magenta">Et Movet</a>
</div>
```

How can I place the image right side of the Text?

Comment: IE7 is the new IE6. better that it get buried and forgotten.

Comment: Wouldn't [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position) work for you?

Comment: @FloydPink By using the background-position I ripped the particular image the from the sprite.Now I want to place the image exactly right side of the anchor tag's text. I hope if you see the code u can understand that...

Comment: @MarcB You are right ..But what to do ..my peoples asks to check in IE 7 too :'(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about adding a `<span>` to the right of the text in the `anchor` tag? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/YHaDw/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>Magenta</p> <a href="#" class="ctrls magenta">Et Movet <span class="icon"></span></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ctrls {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.ctrls:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.ctrls .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(http://jstiles.com/temp/1360875952/ctrls/css-sprite.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position:0px -144px;
}
.ctrls:hover .icon {
    background-position: 0px -252px;
}
```

Comment: I need to give it to the developers.So I cant able to explain them each and every time to add the span.Any other solutions... ?(without Javascript)

Comment: If `:after` and an additional `span` doesn't work, and you want to position a sprite background, I do not know any other options. All the best !

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your code, the result seems to be as you want: [Mylinktext]<MyImagehere>. I'm probably missing something. Try and explain what and will try and help you out.

Personally, I wouldn't use a sprite. Instead, I would make one image per color (I find that easier to work with) or, even better, make a font with the character I want (reference: http://mashable.com/2011/11/17/free-font-creation-tools/; I haven't tried any of the programs, so I don't know how good they are)
 and then use the @font-face Rule (reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp).